# request and urllib2 get error from XBRL page. 'The browser mode you are running is not compatible with this application'

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

Not sure why I can't get the page from this link. All I want to do is get it and feed into beautifulsoup.

```
import requests,urllib2

link='https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1373715/000137371518000157/now-2018630x10q.htm'

r = requests.get(link)

r2=urllib2.urlopen(link)
html=r2.read()
```

also tried faking a browser with:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
```

Text is the same... not the page I want.

Getting a header that looks like this

```
var note = 'The browser mode you are running is not compatible with this application.';

            browserName ='Microsoft Internet Explorer';

            note +='You are currently running '+browserName+' '+((ie7>0)?7:8)+'.0.';       

                var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();           

                if(userAgent.indexOf('ipad') != -1 || userAgent.indexOf('iphone') != -1 || userAgent.indexOf('apple') != -1){               

                    note += ' Please use a more current version of '+browserName+' in order to use the application.';

                }else if(userAgent.indexOf('android') != -1){               

                    note += ' Please use a more current version of Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox in order to use the application.';

                }else{              

                    note += ' Please use a more current version of Microsoft Internet Explorer, Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox in order to use the application.';

                }
```

I can get this page fine: 
`https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1373715/000137371518000153/erq2fy18-document.htm`

which is not a XBRL document. I think it has something to do with the XBRL and the server wants my browser to interact with the data?

Comment: but what is your results? could you add it?

Comment: what's your python version? I run code just now, it worked well.

Comment: 2.7.15... you got the actual 10-Q and a bunch of financial statement numbers?

Comment: no, but I haven't got error you met. I haven't got `a bunch of financial statement numbers`, because the data from js loading.

Comment: I think you can add your error information?

Comment: I get a `200` response. so there is no "error" but the text isn't right.

Comment: what do you want to get? Is the data in website?

Comment: yeah, just what you see when you visit it in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this part of the page is rendered by js. Usually the most reliable option for dynamic content is `selenium`, but in this case you can avoid it and use `requests`.

It is obvious that the page uses the contents of this document `/Archives/edgar/data/1373715/000137371518000157/now-2018630x10q.htm`. You can bypass that page and request the document directly.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1373715/000137371518000157/now-2018630x10q.htm"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

print(html)
```

Comment: I think your answer just saved me a ton of headache. Side steps XBRL all together.